# On Redux-Form Validations disappear because the actions UNREGISTERED_FIELD/REGISTER_FIELD are triggered (twice)

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I am using React 16, Redux-form 7
I have a field with a validation. When I change the value the UPDATE_SYNC_ERRORS is triggered and syncErrors correctly added to the state. Then automatically two series of UNREGISTERED_FIELD/REGISTER_FIELD are triggered and the syncErrors are eliminated and never recreated, even though the value of the field is still incorrect.

```
<Field
    name="afield"
    validate={[ required, number, minValue(100) ]}
    component={props => <AnInput options={options} {...props} />}
  />

    const AnInput = props => {
  const {
    options: { label, prompt, helpText },
    input,
    meta: { touched, dirty, error, warning }
  } = props;

  return (
    <div className="form-group">
      <label>
        {label}
      </label>
      <div >
        <input
          {...input}
        />
        {touched &&
          ((error && <span>{error}</span>) ||
            (warning && <span>{warning}</span>))}
      </div>
      {helpText && <FieldHelp title={label} helpText={helpText} />}
    </div>
  );
};
```

[Actions triggered when field is changed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLeLf.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are calling a function in the validation.
You should use something like this:

```
const min100 = minValue(100);
```

Take a look here https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/3405